# Android App is not visible on Google Play store for tablets

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-permissions

Can anyone suggest me why this app is not visible for tablets on google play store.
I am using GCM, Gmap, Camera and storing files on sdcard.

It is not visible for major tablets on google play store, sim and simless.
I do know that google play store mask app from device which not match with manifest permissions however I believe that there no any permission which is not exist on major samsung devices.

Please find below manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.app"
android:versionCode="15"
android:versionName="2.4.3" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<!-- GOOGLE CLOUD MESSAGING SECION -->
<permission
    android:name="com.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<!-- END GOOGLE CLOUD MESSAGING SECION -->

<permission android:name="com.example.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:allowClearUserData="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <!-- GOOGLE CLOUD MESSAGING SECION -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.app.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.example.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.example.app.GCMRegistrationService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
    <!-- END GOOGLE CLOUD MESSAGING SECTION -->

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

Comment: Could be the devices not having cameras, GPS etc. Try making some of your permissions optional and see if that improves things

Comment: I have published app on BETA and checking supporting devices and it showing that this many devices can support however app NOT visible on those devices. I am logged in that supported device(Samsung Tab) as a tester with using google account. Device  has camera and GPS too. Still its not visible new version which I have published on BETA.

Comment: If you login as your test user and go to the Google Play Store link on your PC does it show your device as not supported?

Comment: It takes an hour or so for changes to propagate on the servers. Have you waited?

Comment: I have gone through all the steps like hitting link to become tester. however the Google account I am using it has attached variety of devices so which supported and which not is still puzzle, still I will try other way. App published yesterday on PLAY store so its already 20 hours. It is also showing me on one of device moto x but not on tablet.

Answer (score 0):

If the Tablet android version below
android:minSdkVersion="11"

Then Google playstore .will not show app in the tablet

Comment: So you mean to say I will have to add android:minSdkVersion="12" not android:minSdkVersion="11" ?

Comment: NO..First check the Table android version , Then if tablet android version less than android:minSdkVersion="11", Then google play store will not show the app,  Example:- Table android OS version 10 , then your application minSDK version 11..then u cant see the app in playstore

Comment: thanks but those all devices has latest OS above 11+. and should be visible on play store.